# Name of Samsung HDD Firmware Assembly language?

Tags: assembly, firmware

Accessing Samsung HDD HD322GJ 320GB SATA terminal via serial TX/RX.

After some research, one person suggested that the command DA means Dumps Assembly. DA dumps 8 words at a time. The dump appears to be encoded instructions/data.

Does anyone know the name of the Assembly language used in this family of HDDs?

```
ENG>DA0
    00000000: E59FF018
    00000004: E59FF018
    00000008: E59FF018
    0000000C: E59FF018
    00000010: E59FF018
    00000014: E320F000
    00000018: E59FF018
    0000001C: E59FF018
ENG>DA20
    00000020: 00003A00
    00000024: 00000040
    00000028: 00000044
    0000002C: 00000048
    00000030: 0000004C
    00000034: 00000000
    00000038: 00000050
    0000003C: 00000050
ENG>DA40
    00000040: EA000010
    00000044: EA00002E
    00000048: EA00003E
    0000004C: EA000046
    00000050: E24EE004
    00000054: E92D5FFF
    00000058: E59F0130
    0000005C: E5900000
ENG>DA60
    00000060: E2000040
    00000064: E3500000
    00000068: 0A000005
    0000006C: E59F011C
    00000070: E5901000
    00000074: E3C11040
    00000078: E5801000
    0000007C: E8BD5FFF
ENG>DA80
    00000080: EA000D5D
    00000084: EA000DCE
    00000088: E24EE004
    0000008C: E92D4000
    00000090: E14FE000
    00000094: E92D5FFF
    00000098: E59F00F0
    0000009C: E5900000
ENG>DA100
```

Comment: That's 8 words at a time, 32 bytes. Not that it matters.

Comment: @Jester - that's a typo thanks. Will correct.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The machine code bytes seem to make sense when decoded as ARM:

```
   0:   e59ff018    ldr pc, [pc, #24]   ; 0x20
   4:   e59ff018    ldr pc, [pc, #24]   ; 0x24
   8:   e59ff018    ldr pc, [pc, #24]   ; 0x28
   c:   e59ff018    ldr pc, [pc, #24]   ; 0x2c
  10:   e59ff018    ldr pc, [pc, #24]   ; 0x30
  14:   e320f000    nop {0}
  18:   e59ff018    ldr pc, [pc, #24]   ; 0x38
  1c:   e59ff018    ldr pc, [pc, #24]   ; 0x3c
  20:   00003A00
  24:   00000040
  28:   00000044
  2c:   00000048
  30:   0000004C
  34:   00000000
  38:   00000050
  3c:   00000050
  40:   ea000010    b   0x88
  44:   ea00002e    b   0x104
  48:   ea00003e    b   0x148
  4c:   ea000046    b   0x16c
  50:   e24ee004    sub lr, lr, #4
  54:   e92d5fff    push    {r0, r1, r2, r3, r4, r5, r6, r7, r8, r9, sl, fp, ip, lr}
  58:   e59f0130    ldr r0, [pc, #304]  ; 0x190
  5c:   e5900000    ldr r0, [r0]
  60:   e2000040    and r0, r0, #64 ; 0x40
  64:   e3500000    cmp r0, #0
  68:   0a000005    beq 0x84
  6c:   e59f011c    ldr r0, [pc, #284]  ; 0x190
  70:   e5901000    ldr r1, [r0]
  74:   e3c11040    bic r1, r1, #64 ; 0x40
  78:   e5801000    str r1, [r0]
  7c:   e8bd5fff    pop {r0, r1, r2, r3, r4, r5, r6, r7, r8, r9, sl, fp, ip, lr}
  80:   ea000d5d    b   0x35fc
  84:   ea000dce    b   0x37c4
  88:   e24ee004    sub lr, lr, #4
  8c:   e92d4000    stmfd   sp!, {lr}
  90:   e14fe000    mrs lr, SPSR
  94:   e92d5fff    push    {r0, r1, r2, r3, r4, r5, r6, r7, r8, r9, sl, fp, ip, lr}
  98:   e59f00f0    ldr r0, [pc, #240]  ; 0x190
  9c:   e5900000    ldr r0, [r0]
```

The 8 entries at 20 form a jump table which are used by the first 8 instructions that seem to be the Interrupt Vector Table.

Comment: what dissembler tool are you using?

Comment: Ok. Well, you are very fast to the draw.  Thanks again!